# Micro Drip Irrigation Backflow Filter (To Protect Pump)

Tags: watering, irrigation, drip-system, water, rain-barrel

I've installed micro irrigation, as:

water butt > pump filter > Shurflo 30psi pump > 16mm supply pipe > 4mm pipe > emitters

Have seen others mention dirt can enter the emitters & eventually backflow to the pump.  It seems either an [inline non-return/check](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/281095326300?_trksid=p2055119.m1438.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT) valve or [inline filter](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/16mm-INLINE-FILTER-POND-HYDROPONICS-IRRIGATION-/161011235395?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&hash=item257d047a43) would be suitable on the pump output, but the budget only allows for one.  Are either really needed, and which connector would be more beneficial?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If backflow is a proper issue then the check valve may be your best option in that its sole purpose is to prevent the backflow of fluids in a system.